# Want to validate if a element text in selenium test ng matches a particular patter

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

Pattern - "5 exceeded expectation"
reuqirement --->element.getText()==pattern

Comment: share more explanations please

Comment: i have an element with text like this - "5 exceeded expectation"
now "5" is variable but  "exceeded expectation" is constant
i need a reg expression to match this pattern

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to handle this.

1. Get the get and then use the substring
2. Use the regular expression
3. find the element using the XPath with only partial text (`exceeded expectation` in this case) Eg: `//span[contains(.,'exceeded expectation')]`

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern you need is `\d exceeded expectation`
The `\d` refers to a digit or numerical character

To test out regex yourself, you can use this site: https://regex101.com/

For a quick guide on the different characters you can use for regular expressions, you can check here: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

To add the verification in your code (using Java):

```
String regex = "\d exceeded expectation";
String elementText = element.getText();
assertTrue(elementText.matches(regex));
```

I think there is a way to add regex into your xpath selectors but I don't know the syntax for that.